# Background changing when picture gallery changes

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have it such that when the user clicks on the picture gallery to change the image, the background image changes as well.

So I've tried using data-slide-index to link them together. For now, I'm just trying to change the background color, instead of the background image. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<p id="back_to_story">
    <a href="story.html">Your Story</a>
</p>

<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row vertical-align">

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12, left-col"> 
            <p><span id="prev"></span></p>      
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" class="content">
          <!--       GALLERY -->
                <ul class="bxslider">
                    <li data-slide-index="0"><img src="assets/slides/image1.jpg"></li>
                    <li data-slide-index="1"><img src="assets/slides/image2.jpg"></li>
                    <li data-slide-index="2"><img src="assets/slides/image3.jpg"></li>
                </ul>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-12, right-col">
            <p><span id="next"></span></p>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            pager:false,
            slideWidth:900,

            touchEnabled: true,
            swipeThreshold: 50,
            oneToOneTouch: true,
            preventDefaultSwipeX: true,
            preventDefaultSwipeY: false,

            controls: true,
            nextSelector: '#next',
            prevSelector: '#prev',
            nextText: 'NEXT',
            prevText: 'PREV'
        });


            if (jQuery('li:visible').data('slide-index')==='0'){
                jQuery('body').css("background-color", "green");
            } else {
                if (jQuery('li:visible').data('slide-index')==='1'){
                jQuery('body').css("background-color", "red");              
            };

     });


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `data` method along with the `:visible` pseudo selector:

```
if (jQuery('li:visible').data('slide-index') === '0') {
    //enter code here
}
```

Comment: @R.ALucus I've added the code using your solution,but it still not working. Will be great if you help to take alook. thanks

Comment: Are the `<li>` elements all visible then?  Do any of them have `display:none`?  How are they toggled between visibility?

Comment: @R.ALucus yes all the <li> elements are visible. i have a gallery jquery called bxSlider that changes the images on click of "prev" and "next".